# I have error in giving background in Android studio by giving value android:background="11000000" my terminal error is posted below

Tags: css, android-layout, android-studio

```
/Users/adityamnaik/AndroidStudioProjects/Alvas/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.adityamnaik.alvas\
        -0\
        apk\
        --preferred-density\
        560dpi\
        --output-text-symbols\
        /Users/adityamnaik/AndroidStudioProjects/Alvas/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors

Output:  /Users/adityamnaik/AndroidStudioProjects/Alvas/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:11: error: '11000000' is incompatible with attribute android:background (attr) reference|color.
/Users/adityamnaik/AndroidStudioProjects/Alvas/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:26: error: '11000000' is incompatible with attribute android:background (attr) reference|color.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

Comment: Post your code too please, where you declare background-color.

Comment: Edit this question appropriately, nobody can break it down this way. Include your code and format it properly.

Comment: You can @mention me when you've done that.

Comment: my code which i declared is for a button showing original background image using android:background="#110000"